# Baffling Xcode Plugin build trouble

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plugins

I'm trying to build an Xcode plugin using this [template](https://github.com/kattrali/Xcode5-Plugin-Template). As a matter of fact the template works perfectly, but the problem is that something strange happened and it stopped loading the plugin. After 3 hours of trial & error, I pinpointed the problem but I cannot get my head around this...

I have a class called `MHStatement` and when I build **without** including this class, the plugin works fine and appears in the Xcode menu bar as expected.

However, when I include the `MHStatement.h` and `MHStatement.m` files in the project and then build, the plugin fails to load.

Now the fun part is that if I rename `MHStatement` to `Statement` and build it still doesn't work.

But if I make a new interface & implementation `Statement` overwriting the above `Statement` files it works again.

Moreover, creating new classes named `_MHStatement`, `__MHStatement`, `MXStatement`, `MBStatment`, `MHFatment` also make it fail, but `XXStatement`, `DDStatement`, `XHStatement` is OK.

But when I create a class `XXStatement`, and refactor->rename it to `MHStatement` and build, 
the plugin loads normally.

This is obviously some weird runtime or linking error, but I don't know how to even start looking for what exactly is happening.

I am not sure if this is reproducible by any means, so I would just kindly ask for any advice that might come to your minds.

Cheers!

EDIT

I tried creating a new class `MHStatement` and adding it to [BBUncustify plugin](https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode). Building the plugin like this also prevents it to load, but now I'm getting this warning

```
objc[6278]: Class MHStatement is implemented in both /Users/marko/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/UncrustifyPlugin and /Users/marko/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/PluginTest3.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/PluginTest3. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

with `tail -f /var/log/system.log`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new project from scratch, and now have 3 separate targets, a framework for the code base that actually does all the work, test cases for the framework, and a simple one class plugin target, which works fine with that setup.

I hope some day someone will be able to answer what exactly was happening, and Apple will become kinder to Xcode modding community.